# how i can know mod_php5.c name

Tags: mod-php

[first see this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/100519/how-i-can-prevent-hackers-when-the-apache-go-away)

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Allow from none
    </FilesMatch>
 RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

now how i can know the mod_php5.c name becuase it not like that in my host
and me is not the host admin this mean i cant see the server

Answer (score 1):

You have this line in your httpd.conf:

> LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

where `php5_module` is the module name you should use in "IfModule" statement.