# is there any other way to deny php files

Tags: php

[see this](https://serverfault.com/questions/100519/how-i-can-prevent-hackers-when-the-apache-go-away)

and this

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Allow from none
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

now i cant know mod_php5.c name
becuase iam is not the server owner
me is just have small host
now is there any other way to do that
this man i want deny access php file when the php is no longer here

Comment: Can you give some more details? It is hard to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: Checking for mod_php5 is very unreliable also because PHP sometimes runs as a normal CGI process... oh, and there are other httpds besides Apache, too.

Comment: It seems to me that the poster wants to disable access to .php files, but only when PHP is NOT enabled. Possibly in order to avoid outputting source code?

Answer (score 1):

Put all files in another folder outside the server root, set a separate file configuring the path to that second folder; after that leave in your web root php files with the same name and include the real files on the fly.

An example for `index.php`:

```
<?php
    require '../mysite_config.inc.php';
    require INCDIR . 'index.php';
?>
```

where `mysite_config.inc.php` contains:

```
<?php
    define('INCDIR', '../the_real_folder/');
?>
```

Comment: +1 Any php files containing sensitive data (eg. MySQL Connection strings) should be in an include file in a directory that is outside the website root. Or at least in a directory that you deny access to regardless of whether PHP is working or not. You don't have to deny access to absolutely every php script, just the sensitive ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny access to all PHP files, you could just use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule *.php accessdenied.html
```

And have a HTML file called "accessdenied.html" which displays an error, or replace "accessdenied.html" above with a link to the page you want the user to be redirected to.